# Suppose that the maximum degree of a graph is less or equal to 2, then all components are path or cycles

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

There is a claim on Pg. 109 of West's graph theory book

> Let $F$ be the symmetric difference of two matchings $M, M'$, then,
>
> "Suppose that the maximum degree of a $F$ is less or equal to 2, then
>   all components are path or cycles"

How would one go about proving this claim? It seems intuitive that the only components obtainable from a graph with degree $\leq$2 is either a path or a cycle. How does one go about ruling out the other cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph with maximum degree $2$, and take any maximal path $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k$ in $G$. (By "maximal" I just mean that it cannot be extended from either endpoint.)

Then the interior vertices of that path $x_2, \dots, x_{k-1}$ already have degree $2$ just considering the edges used by the path. So they have no more edges out of them. The endpoints $x_1$ and $x_k$ don't have edges to any other vertices of $G$ (or the path wouldn't be maximal), so $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k\}$ induce a connected component of $G$.

This connected component cannot have any edges $(x_i, x_j)$ with $1 < i < k$ or $j < i < k$, beyond what's already in the path, since that would boost the degree of $x_i$ or $x_j$ to 3. This rules out all but one potential edge: the edge $(x_1, x_k)$. If it is present, then the connected component induced by $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k\}$ is a cycle; if it is absent, then the connected component is a path.